# Not able to download Page blob type file from Azure blob storage using SSIS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, ssis-2012, blobstorage

In SSIS job, I added a step for download files from Azure Blob Storage. After adding a Azure Blob Download task, in the control flow, and entering in the storage configuration (Test connection successfully).

But it download only **Block blob** type file only.  Not able to download **Page blob** type files.

How we can download page blob type file using SSIS?  If anyone have other approach then it also fine for me.

Comment: using for each container and Flexible File task component, we can download the Page blob file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using for each container and Flexible File task component, we can download the Page blob file.